# Webpack 2 doesn't parse CSS files

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I'm upgrading webpack to 2.2 on my project and I'm facing an odd issue right now.

Webpack is parsing my JS files without a problem but when it comes to stylesheets - it seems that it ignores the /.css$/ rule in my config and throws an error while trying to parse it. I've updated every possible loader to latest stable version but cant find the bug.

Error that I keep getting:

```
Module parse failed: /project/src/assets/css/main.css Unexpected token (1:5)
[0] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
[0] | body {
[0] |     background: black;
[0] | }
```

Link to webpack.config.js is [here](https://gist.github.com/vaclav-zeman/98d3789d2141037885c0e4dd26e5e810).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having CSS as entry point is actually allowed. I actually found the issue -
it started working when I removed this [line](https://gist.github.com/vaclav-zeman/98d3789d2141037885c0e4dd26e5e810#file-gistfile1-txt-L27), that includes the dir.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think css files are allowed as entry points. Either try requiring your css within your js or if you'd prefer to keep your css as an entry point try a plugin like https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-entry-webpack-plugin